# Flex Spark List scroll to bottom when new data is added

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I have a Spark List (`spark.components.List`) backed by an ArrayCollection for its dataProvider. The List has a vertical scrollbar when there's too many rows to display. What I want is when a new row is added to the List for it to scroll to the bottom to show that new row.

I've tried calling List's `ensureIndexIsVisible` from a listener on the ArrayCollection. This doesn't work because the List hasn't yet fully rendered the new row. It will either scroll to the second from the last row, or throw the exception:

```
Error: invalidIndex
 at spark.layouts.supportClasses::LinearLayoutVector/start()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\layouts\supportClasses\LinearLayoutVector.as:893]
 at spark.layouts.supportClasses::LinearLayoutVector/getBounds()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\layouts\supportClasses\LinearLayoutVector.as:1117]
 at spark.layouts::VerticalLayout/getElementBounds()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\layouts\VerticalLayout.as:852]
 at spark.layouts.supportClasses::LayoutBase/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::getScrollPositionDeltaToElementHelper()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\layouts\supportClasses\LayoutBase.as:1367]
 at spark.layouts.supportClasses::LayoutBase/getScrollPositionDeltaToElement()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\layouts\supportClasses\LayoutBase.as:1348]
 at spark.components::List/ensureIndexIsVisible()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\List.as:2105]
```

I've made sure that my listener is added to the ArrayCollection after setting List's dataProvider. The hope is that I'd be calling `ensureIndexIsVisible` after the List got a chance to process the new row. My guess is that the List doesn't render the row until some redraw event that occurs later (after I've called `ensureIndexIsVisible`).

I've also tried specifying a `VerticalLayout` and setting its `verticalScrollPosition` to an overly large number (like 99999). This has the same problem - it scrolls to the second from the last row.

So, is there a way to scroll to a newly added row in a Spark List? The only I could find on the Internet is this [poorly formatted flexcoders thread](http://www.pubbs.net/201002/flex/41604-flexcoders-scroll-to-bottom-on-a-spark-list-when-data-changes.html).

Comment: Did you try to call `ensureIndexIsVisible()` in a `callLater`? Like `callLater(function():void { ensureIndexIsVisible(lastIndex) });`

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it didn't work, apparently callLater is not being called later enough. I did use setTimeout and it does work but that's very hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to extend `List` and override `updateDisplayList`, which works:

```
protected override function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    // call ensureIndexIsVisible here
}
```

See discussion on [Adobe's forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3193587).

Comment: this only works sometimes, you need to wait about .03 seconds to call this, setTimeout works, but likely you need a CallLater utility class to handle this for you.  Message me if you need one that works well...

Comment: `callLater(myList.ensureIndexIsVisible, [myData.length - 1])` still throws exceptions in some cases

Answer (score 4):

Instead of extending `List` in order to override `updateDisplayList`, I added a listener to the `FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE` on my `List` component and it works just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when ensureIndexIsVisible is run directly after an insert to a list dataProvider it does not accurately pull the position of the last item in the list. This looks to be because the binding has not had a chance to update the list. The fastest solution for me was to run a callLater on ensureIndexIsVisible.

```
_acGuestBookMessages.addItemAt(obj, _acGuestBookMessages.length);
var arr:Array = [_acGuestBookMessages.length-1];
callLater(lstGuestBookMessages.ensureIndexIsVisible, arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Want to scroll to bottom of an updating spark list and 
**ensureIndexIsVisible** is too much undocumented trouble? 
I got this to work by dealing with the physical height of dataGroup property on List...

```
function newMessage(...)
{
    messages.addItemAt(msg, messages.length);               
    messages.refresh();
    scrollToBottom();
}

function scrollToBottom():void
{
    messagesList.addEventListener("updateComplete", scrollUpdate);
}

private function scrollUpdate(e:Event):void
{
    messagesList.removeEventListener("updateComplete", scrollUpdate);
    messagesList.dataGroup.verticalScrollPosition = messagesList.dataGroup.contentHeight - messagesList.dataGroup.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(itemsList && itemsList.scroller && 
   itemsList.scroller.verticalScrollBar && 
   itemsList.scroller.verticalScrollBar.visible){

       itemsList.scroller.verticalScrollBar.value = 
          itemsList.scroller.verticalScrollBar.maximum;

}
```

Comment: A little explanation would made your post more valuable ;)

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same problem, this works for me -

```
if(chatCollection.length > 0)
{
    chatList.validateNow();
    chatList.ensureIndexIsVisible(chatCollection.length - 1);
}
```